# Remote app doesn't work

Tags: itunes, home-sharing, apple-remote-desktop

After I key in the code for pairing the remote app on iTunes, the app just shows "Looking for ..." for a long while, then says "could not find".

[image: remote app fail]

After that, the library seems to appear on the library screen of the remote app, but it doesn't have a name! There's an icon with no label below...

Pretty odd. Googling shows that many others are having similar issues, but no one seems to have a solution.

I've also tried to use "home sharing" to use the app, also doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite still.

I fixed this by simply changing the computer name of my mac running iTunes!

Go on your Mac to System Preferences -> Sharing and change the computer name.

Now the iTunes Library appears properly with Home Sharing and also by the 4 digit code.

Very strange, though.